# How to access this.state of a class in Bottom navigation bar (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-bottomnav, android-bottomappbar

**I want to access this.state of Class MainAct in bottom navigation bar. So that when this.state updates navigation bar rerenders**.

Here is my code.

I want to access 'this.state.data' in 'MainAct' of bottom navigation bar. (or any alternatives)

And is exporting createMaterialBottomTabNavigator as default OK?

```js
//jshint ignore: start
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
} from 'react-native';
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';


class MainAct extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: 'Hello World'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.parent}>
                <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
    Screen1: {
        screen: Screen1,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Screen1',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Image source={me} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
            )
        }
    },
    Screen2: {
        screen: Screen2,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Screen2',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Image source={Chat} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
            )
        }
    },
    Screen3: {
        screen: Screen3,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Screen3',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Image source={homeIcon} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
            )
        }
    },
    MainAct: {
        screen: MainAct,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'MainAct',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <View>
                    <View style={{ display: 'flex'}}>
                        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', right: -8, top: -5, backgroundColor: '#4CAF50', borderRadius: 200, height: 14, paddingLeft: 4, paddingRight: 4, zIndex: 5 }}>
                            <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 0, color: '#FFFFFF', fontSize: 10 }}>{this.state.data}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                    <Image source={noti} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
                </View>

            )
        }
    },
    Screen5: {
        screen: Screen5,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Screen5',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Image source={new1} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
            )
        }
    },
}, {
        initialRouteName: 'MainAct',
        activeColor: '#000000',
        inactiveColor: '#000000',
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', height: 60, elevation: 0, shadowColor: 0 },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `BottomNavigator` has to access the state of your screen, your state is probably in the wrong place. You should think about having a global state for your app since the dataflow in React should be unidirectional and parent components shouldn't just get access to a child's state.

There are various ways to do this, like [redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux), [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx), [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), or whatever state management library you like. If you have a global state, both the `BottomNavigator` and `MainAct` can have access to it.